# SQLite - Joining Tables using Django

Tags: django, sqlite

I am not a coder by any means but I have to do a project for college and I am really stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Django and SQLite. I want to join the auth_user table with an input table that I created. I have run the following SQL join which has given me the result I want.(Which is that every user has there own waist measurement) But my issue is I don't know how to implement this into Django? 
This is my SQL statement:

[Sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AAb0.png)

Please Help!

Comment: Posting SQL is not helpful - and linking to a picture of SQL is even less helpful. What we need to see is the definition of your "input table" and an example of the output you want - in the question, as text.

Answer (score 0):

Django has its own ORM ([Making queries | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)). So that you specify the table structure with the models. I'll give you an example

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class AuthUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_lenth=250
    )

class ProjectInput(models.Model):
    auth_user = models.ForeignKey(to='AuthUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    waist = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

so you create `AuthUser` model and `ProjectInput` model and you have foreign key relation between them ([Models | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/)).

so with this models you can create the query in Django ORM like

```
full_name_waist = ProjectInput.objects.values_list('auth_user__full_name', 'waist')
```

these are the very basics od Django. **I suggest you reading tutorials in the django - [Getting Started | Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/)**.

more sources:

[Django ORM - Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/django-orm.html)